# Modifying a list of ticker symbols in sas by deleting the last few characters

Tags: sas, finance

I have a long list of time-series price data sorted by ticker symbol and then by date. I'm looking to delete the last four characters on every ticker. Say the ticker is AAA.ASX, I would like to end up with just AAA to match and merge with another data set.

So far I've tried to code:

`asx=tranwrd(asx,".asx","");
put asx;
run;`

Any advice would be appreciated as I'm just getting into this whole sas thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand upon Joe's answer slightly, `scan` includes `.` as one of it's standard delimiters and so the third argument is not strictly necessary (but it's good practice to be explicit).

```
data tmp;
    asx = "abc.def";

    /* Return the first word, when seperated by . */ 
    asx1 = scan(asx, 1, ".");
    put asx1=;

    /* Return the first word, when seperated by standard delimiters _ -,."' etc. */ 
    asx2 = scan(asx, 1);
    put asx2=;

    /* Return only the first 3 characters (if you know it will always be 3 long) */
    asx3 = substr(asx, 1, 3);
    put asx3=;

    /* Return the substring from position 1 to the first occourance of . */
    asx4 = substr(asx, 1, index(asx, ".") - 1);
    put asx4=;
run;
```

As your learning SAS it may also be worth your while to check out some of the other string manipulation functions like `substr` and `index` as it's great to have multiple tools available.

Comment: I'll give these functions a shot and let you know how I go. Thanks for code.

Answer (score 0):

`scan` is probably your best bet, if it's consistently the first 'word' separated by dot.

```
ticker_short = scan(ticker_long,1,'.'); *second argument is which word you want, third optional is which delimiter;
```